# Why is the max element value in a numpy array 255?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am currently using numpy to create an array. I would like to use vectorized implementations to more efficiently take the average of the elements in a position, (i, j). These arrays are coming from images in a file directory which have all been standardized to a fixed size.

However, when I try to add the image arrays, the sum of each element is returned in a form a (mod 256). How can I change the maximum value of the elements?

Comment: I would say that your array is of `uint8` type. Use `numpy.astype` to make another array with desired variable type. For example `y = x.astype(numpy.uint16)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays are presumably of type `numpy.uint8`, so they wraparound when they hit 256.

If you want to get larger results, use `astype` to convert the first argument to a larger data type, e.g.:

```
a = np.array(..., dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array(..., dtype=np.uint8)
c = a.astype(np.uint32) + b
```

and you'll get a result array of the larger data type too.

[Per @Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982605/why-is-the-max-element-value-in-a-numpy-array-255/40982730#comment69176330_40982730), to avoid the temporary, you can use [the numpy `add` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add) (not method) to do the addition, passing a `dtype` so the result is of the new type even as the inputs are not converted, avoiding a temporary (at least at the Python level):

```
c = np.add(a, b, dtype=np.uint32)
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `c = np.add(a, b, dtype=np.uint32)` to avoid making a temporary copy of `a` (that is 4x bigger than `a`)

Comment: @Eric: I tried doing something like that, but apparently the interactive interpreter docs and [numpy online docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add) lied to me (they only mentioned an `out` param, and it didn't actually avoid the overflow issue). Added that to the answer; I wanted something like that in the first place.

Comment: I guess you have to know about `ufuncs` to know that param is available: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off creating the output array first:

```
average = numpy.zeros(a.shape, numpy.float32)
image = numpy.zeros_like(average)
```

Then traversing the images and adding them up in-place:

```
for i in images:
    image[:] = function_that_reads_images_as_uint8(i)
    average += image
average /= len(images)
```

You might get away with int types if you didn't need the precision in the division step.

Comment: Or you could just write `np.mean(images, dtype=np.float32)`, which avoids the manual looping that you should never use in numpy.

Comment: @Eric: Unless you are willing to stack all the images in a single multidim ndarray (which could be memory-prohibitive for a large number of images), this approach is superior. My approach requires only two arrays of the same shape, one for the image currently being read, the other for the result. I am also quite surprised to see such statements about looping. Looping can be a sign that you are not taking full advantage of vectorization, but it is by no means evil, especially when it comes to working with larger data or datasets where memory use is a concern.

Comment: Your approach requires 3 arrays, because `.astype(numpy.float32)` makes an unecessary copy. But you're right, I hadn't considered memory constraints in that comment, and in this case looping is reasonable